# Cache strategy for google places api nearby result.

Tags: api, google-maps, caching, geolocation

Im trying to figure out how i would go about caching the result i get back from a nearby search. So i can get upto 60 places based upon my current long lat position.
So im thinking that if user1 ask google for nearby places within a radius of 1km from position long: xxx lat: xxx. And i get a result back with places. And then user2 is asking for nearby places 500m away from user1. Then i would like to be able to use the cached data that user1 already fetched from google.

Any suggestion on how i would go about implement this kind of functionality?
Or should i just cache each place by their long,lat and implement my own geosearch?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built in google maps library that allows you to do radius search without calling the server. Best bet would be to make your own geosearch on the fetched points or use an open source library to help you.

If you do use cached data but remember that there's no guarantee how much of the 60 places fetched in a 1km radius are also within the 500m radius. If you did another query for 60 places within a 500m radius you'd get more accurate information.

Disclaimer: Google has certain rules in place about caching data. 10.5 d) https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10